# How to make a scrollable section inside div that fills in all the remaining space of said div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a div with a bunch of different sections, one of which is a scrollable list within the div.

The scrollable area varies depending on the screen size and needs to occupy all the remaining space of the parent. So far, I only know how to make it scroll if I specify the scrollable div's height. This of course, will not have a once size fits all when dealing with different screen sizes.

If I alternatively set my scrollable div's height to 100%, I then of course lose my ability to scroll. So that's no good either.

How can I solve this?

Here is a sample app illustrating the problem:

```js
const App = () => {

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>
        <h2>My Content</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>
        <h3>Scrollable section that must fill in the rest of the space</h3>
        <div className="scrollable-div">
          {[...Array(50).keys()].map((_, index) => (
            <div>item {index}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scrollable-div {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 3px solid red;
  /*
  this all works fine, but I need the scroll section to go all the way to the end of the parent div,
  regardless of the screen size. How can I do this without setting a fixed height here?
  */
  height: 250px;
  /*
    the alternative, which would allow this div to expand all the way down to the reminder of the parent
    is set height to 100%, however then I lose my ability to scroll.
  */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Comment: In your case, add height: 100vh; to .scrollable-div and it will occupy the rest of the window regardless of its size.

Comment: @bigless it does not I'm afraid. If it weren't for the need to scroll, this would not be a problem.

Comment: @GLAPPsMobile yes it will, however a bunch of the items on the list are now inaccessible as the scroll does not go all the way down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run snippet, and click 'full page' then scale browser and scrolling area should be dynamic in height.  Only tested in Chrome btw.

```js
const App = () => {

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="inner">
        <h2>My Content</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>
        <h3>Scrollable section that must fill in the rest of the space</h3>
        <div className="scrollable-div">
          {[...Array(50).keys()].map((_, index) => (
            <div>item {index}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid #2B3239;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.inner {
  padding: 12px;
  background: #EFF2F5;
  min-height: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.scrollable-div {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid #FF6F6F;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hum... But that is not scrollable. When running on fullscreen, it just expands the whole scrollable-div area. And on smaller screens, it is shrunk enough that it shows nothing.

Comment: Are you sure?  Take a look at the screen recording when I 'run snippet' and then 'full page' and size browser...https://streamable.com/nd1dyy

Comment: I think you clicked 'expand snippet' and then 'run code snippet'...that would not display properly....I should have clarified....click 'Run snippet', and then click 'full page' and it should work as expected.

Comment: Weird that it didn't work when running the snippet normally. Indeed that does the job. THanks!